# Why constructor is not being called in member function of another class in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have two classes: `Age` and `Animal`.

I thought that constructor of `Age` should be called twice:

- first time on `Animal a = Animal(13);`
- second time on `a.getAge();` (because of `Age temp(age);` in function definition)

But... output of `main()` is `Age constructor!` instead of `Age constructor!Age constructor!`, so it seems like this constructor is called only once (I have checked that it is called on constructing `Animal` object.). ***Why?***

Here is my code:

```
class Age {
private:
    int value;
public:
    Age(int a) :value(a) { cout << "Age constructor!"; }
};

class Animal {
private:
    Age age;
public:
    Animal(int a) : age(a) {}
    Age getAge() const { Age temp(age); return temp; }
};

void main() {   
    Animal a = Animal(13);

    a.getAge();
}
```

Comment: You have [*copy elision*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: BTW, you should have `const Age& getAge() const { return age; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Age constructor inside getAge() invokes the copy constructor, which is compiler generated in this case. The constructor taking an int is not invoked there.

It's also notable that the construction of the return value out of getAge() is (almost certainly) elided. But again, the elided construction is the copy/move construction, so no output would be produced even if it were not elided.

Answer (score 5):

```
Age temp(age);
```

It's call to copy constructor, not default. So, write copy constructor and add trace to it, if you want to see, that copy was created.

Answer (score 0):

We constructing new object temp based on existing object age so u need to define
copy constructor in your base class